# What is the unit of the texels in a depth texture?

Tags: opengl, directx, rendering, shader

Suppose we've got a framebuffer with a depth attachment related to a texture called `depthTexture`. If we bind this texture to the pipeline and read a value `depth = texture2D(depthTexture, texCoord)` in the next rendering pass, what is the unit of `depth`?

Let's be more specific: Suppose we've set up a camera with near plane at `near` and far plane at `far` (in view-space coordinates). As far as I know, the depth values from the previous pass, stored in `depthTexture`, are multiplied by the projection matrix. Thus, we would need to modify `depth` in the following way:

```
depth = 2 * near * far / (far + near - (far - near) *
    (2 * texture2D(gDepthTexture, tex).x - 1));
```

However: I want to know, wheter this transformation is necessary or not and what's the unit of `depth` (before and afterwards).

I want to be able to compare `depth` with world coordinate distances.

Comment: If you are asking what a depth texture stores, that is *window-space* Z. This is the value of Z after NDC [**0**,**1**] in D3D [**-1**,**1**] in GL goes through the viewport transformation (more importantly the depth-range part of that transformation). The `near` and  `far` values are generally in *view-space*, by the way, not *world-space* -- they represent distance  down the *view-space* Z-axis.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I want to compare values from `depthTexture` with distances from the camera, i.e. check if `depth` is more than 10 units away from the camera (measured in view-space coordinates).

Comment: Rather than try to explain this process in a long comment, what you want has already been implemented [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Compute_eye_space_from_window_space), for OpenGL (emphasis on the shader at the end). You will have to compensate for D3D's wacky NDC convention if you really want an answer that covers both APIs.

Answer (score 2):

The depth you sample from the depth buffer is in *screen-space* (aka *window-space*) and is non-linear in regard to *world-* or *view-space* (aka *eye-space*). It has some good properties regarding rasterization, but can not be used to measure distances in world space.

When you modify the depth as shown in your question you calulate the *view-space* depth, which is linear and measured in the same unit as your *world-space* (but is transformed to have the camera at [0, 0, 0]). So yes, the transformation is necessary, and you can compare your depth in *world-space* units afterward.

Just be aware that depth means "distance from the camera plane" and not "distance from the camera".

[image: Difference between distance and depth.]

Comment: No it's not (in *eye-space*, that is). The depth buffer stores the depth ***after*** projection, perspective division and viewport transformation (depth range). *Eye-space* is a synonym for *view-space*; ***window-space*** is probably the synonym you were looking for.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I'm more familiar with the DirectX terminology, but I figured since the question uses OpenGL I should include that terminology as well. It's now fixed.